# Pylinter on sublime 3 doesn't work

Tags: sublimetext3, pylint

My pylinter setting is:

```
{
    // When versbose is 'true', various messages will be written to the console.
    // values: true or false
    // "verbose": false,
    // The full path to the Python executable you want to
    // run Pylint with or simply use 'python'.
    "python_bin": "somewhere/bin/python",
    // Optionally set the working directory
    // "working_dir": null,
    // Full path to the lint.py module in the pylint package
    "pylint_path": "somewhere/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylint/lint.py",
    // Optional full path to a Pylint configuration file
    // "pylint_rc": null,
    // Set to true to automtically run Pylint on save
    "run_on_save": true,
    // Set to true to use graphical error icons
    "use_icons": true,
    "disable_outline": false,
    "message_stay": true,
}
```

However, when I saved a python script, nothing happened.

Comment: "*I saved a python script, nothing happenned*": Do you mean that it was not saved? or that the disk led did not blink?

Comment: I mean, I couldn't see the result of pylint.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the shortcut?

**OS X:** `Command+Alt+z`

**Linux, Windows:** `Control+Alt+z`